# Aplicações hibridas otimizam o webview?

Tags: android, ionic

Como os *frameworks* híbridos trabalham? Na minha visão o que eles fazem é rodar tudo em cima do *webview* nativo da plataforma, só empacotando o código JS dentro de um diretório da aplicação, como por exemplo o *assets*.

Então qual é a real utilidade de utilizar esses *frameworks*? É só para ter um código multiplataforma e desenvolver um produto rápido?

Em teoria, pensando no Android, se eu tivesse um código minemo que carrega uma pagina HTML num *webview* é a mesma coisa que criar um app em IONIC e montar pra Android? Esses *frameworks* otimizam alguma coisa?

Comment: Com uma aplicação hibrida, você terá a capacidade de desenvolver aplicativos para três ou mais plataformas distintas, de forma mais rápida, sem se preocupar muito com os recursos nativos de determinada plataforma. veja o caso do webview que é utilizado para carregar um página web ou um arquivo interno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1 - Cordova

Bem, não é apenas isso. O que ocorre é que a parte de visualização do app, roda em cima do webview, porém o cordova fornece uma integração nativa com os recursos do próprio dispositivo. A grande vantagem além da velocidade de desenvolvimento é você não ter que se preocupar com os padrões de componentes de cada plataforma, uma vez que os plugins lidam com eles para você.

O Ionic (que trabalha em cima do cordova), cria um objeto chamado window.cordova, que permite o acesso direto de api do sistema. O que permite que você faça uma chamada por javascript, e internamente o cordova detecte a plataforma em que se está sendo executado e então execute a ferramenta apropriada para ele. É possível acessar câmera, acelerômetro, microfone, arquivos, localização e qualquer outro recurso do seu dispositivo, contando que seja desenvolvido um plugin para isso (que até você mesmo pode fazer).

Vale a pena se manter atualizado olhando os plugins desenvolvidos para cordova, recentemente foi criado um para usar animações nativas, caixas de diálogo nativas e transição de páginas nativas. Tem realmente muita coisa bacana que dá pra você implementar no seu app, cada vez fica mais difícil diferenciar um app nativo de um app desenvolvido baseado em cordova.

## 2 - React Native

Existe também como criar apps híbridas utilizando js sem ser em cima de web views. Esse é o caso do [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/), uma plataforma desenvolvida pelos desenvolvedores do facebook (inclusive é usada nos apps do facebook). Ela permite que você crie códigos apps multiplataforma nativos usando o React, e as vantagens dela são uma performance melhor que a opção anterior e como o cordova também permite, ter menos dor de cabeça com outras plataformas.

Comment: Para obter essa tal transição de páginas nativas, baseando que o aplicativo esta rodando em cima de um webview, eles otimazam então o código do webview ou mesmo criam um próprio para obter esse resultado?

Comment: @LF Ziron Ótima resposta!

Comment: @PauloGustavo Ele continua usando webview, porém ele faz um hack para trocar a página utilizando o recurso do S.O

Answer (score 1):

Quando você usa uma arquitetura híbrida, pode ter de criar "pontes" entre a camada HTML5 e a camada nativa para acessar recursos nativos da plataforma. Por exemplo, acessar contatos do celular.

Normalmente você teria de selecionar um método de comunicação entre o Javascript e o código nativo (que não é algo trivial, infelizmente) e também implementar essa comunicação para a tarefa que você está fazendo.

A vantagem de usar um framework tipo Cordova é que esse tipo de coisa já foi feita, seja no framework em si, seja em algum plug-in.

A desvantagem é que há a curva do aprendizado do framework, que não é pequena no caso do Cordova; e você "casa" com ele, ficando sujeito aos humores futuros do projeto de framework.

Minha opinião pessoal: o Cordova era mais vantajoso quando havia 4 ou 5 plataformas mobile viáveis (iOS, Android, Windows Phone, Blackberry, Tizen, Meego...) No momento o mercado reduziu-se para iOS e Android, apenas. Implementar apenas a lógica de negócio em Javascript, e usar React Native ou mesmo view nativa vai proporcionar um resultado melhor com menos dependência de framework.

Comment: Então se você fosse criar um aplicativo escrito em Javascript, usarias nativo para não ter dependências com frameworks? Meus questionamentos não são porque quero rodar um app multiplataforma, e sim entender a real vantagem (além de ser multiplataforma) de ser usar um framework desses. Estou criando um app em JS que irá rodar nativo android em cima do webview, entre tanto me questionei várias vezes se esses frameworks fazem alguma mágica que deixam o webview mais rapidos e tal.

Comment: Eu usaria Views nativos, sim. A parte mais reutilizável de um aplicativo é o Modelo ou "regras de negócio", essa faz sentido aplicar um esforço de reutilização. As views mudam o tempo todo, e não acredito muito que um app possa ser atraente com View HTML5. A única situação em que faz sentido usar HTML5 pra tudo é se você já tem um site, ele já funciona muito bem em mobile, só que você quer oferecer uma presença um pouco mais "institucional", ou seja, um app na loja em vez de mandar o usuário abrir o browser. Acho que bancos também usam HTML5 mas aí com a intenção de estabelecer canal seguro.

Answer (score 0):

Para quem desenvolve aplicações nativas com a IDE Android Studio, tenho um exemplo rápido de Webview:

Crie um arquivo index.html em assets e mude seu arquivo MainActivity.java, como feito abaixo:

```
package br.com.webview.android;

import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton; 
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

Veja que acima eu chamei o webview através de uma `id` chamada `checkbox_webview`.

Para chamar a activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Sua tela webview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="08dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="08dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
            android:textColorLink="#309BE3"
            android:background="#f2f2f2"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:contextClickable="true"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:importantForAccessibility="auto"/>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Espero ter ajudado.